# Is “healing faster than I thought I was going to” grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, past-tense, present-tense

I told I friend that “I’ve been healing faster than I thought I was going to” in relation to a breakup. I’ve been thinking that I should’ve said “I’ve been healing faster than I thought I would.” Which one would be grammatically correct?

Comment: Hi Yerika. Welcome to ELL! They're both grammatically OK. The second is more concise and would be perfect in any context. The first is fine in an informal context. You could also say *...than I expected.*

Comment: This is really helpful. That question was my first inquiry on this platform. Thank you so much!